# What is the difference between $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ and $f'(x)$?

Tags: derivatives, notation

In highschool we had to write it like $f'(x)$. But isn't that the same as writing it as $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$?

- If nay, what is the difference?
- If yay, why did we wrote it like that in highschool?

Comment: It's the same, indeed.

Comment: They are the same thing. The former is Newton's notation, the latter Leibniz's.

Comment: Perhaps interesting: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-is-the-difference-between-calculus-of-newton-and-that-of-leibniz#:~:text=Newton%27s%20calculus%20is%20about%20functions,limit%20is%20a%20separate%20operation.

Comment: Historically, people would write $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ to mean $$\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx} \, ,$$where $dx$ was an 'infinitely small' non-zero number. Because such numbers don't exist in the real number system, nowadays people typically interpret $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ as the limit $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \, ,$$or as the result of applying the derivative operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ to $f(x)$. Regardless of your interpretation, $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=f'(x)$ always.

Comment: The difference is just of notation

Comment: In calculus (university) we still used $f'(x)$ we only used $d/dx f(x) $ in differential equations.

Comment: If there is a difference, it's purely aesthetic. For example, I think expressing the derivative at a point is better served by the "prime" notation, $f'(c)$, as opposed to, say, $\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}\big|_{x=c}$.

Comment: There is no difference. However, the "$\frac{df}{dx}$ notation" is very useful if your function $f$ has more than one variable. The partial derivatives of, say, a function $f(x,y)$ are written as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same. We use the $f'(x)$ or more generally $f^{(n)}(x)$ to save space.

:)