# Difference between the $f'(x)$ and the $ \frac {d}{dx}$ notation for derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have been studying calculus and something I have noticed is that for the derivatives we use $f'(x)$ while in my calculator it is presented as $\frac{d}{dx}$.

I was wondering if there was a difference between the two notations and if they represent different things

Comment: This may help you: [The differences between Lagrange and Leibniz's derivative notations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3797758)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ and $f'(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158091/what-is-the-difference-between-fracddxfx-and-fx) - obtained from [Tyma Gaidash's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743279/difference-between-the-fx-and-the-frac-ddx-notation-for-derivatives#comment10061178_4743279) above.